# How to position image relative to text?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to create an effect where I have centered text, but an image on either side of the text, to look like this

```
|                    |
|        text[image] |
| [image]text        |
|                    |
```

I want the text to be centered relative to the div, but I want to image to sit on either side of the text. How can I achieve this? Here is my html and css now:

```
<div class="text-container">
  <h1 class="text">text1</h1><span class="image"><img src="image.svg"></span>
</div> 

text-container {
    text-align: center;
}
text {
    display: inline;
}
```

The issue with this is that the `image` also gets treated as an inline element, so the whole structure, instead of just the text, is centered. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you considered floating the image left or right?

Comment: I've tried, but then my text is no longer aligned center for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

hi here is the code for your image next to text:

HTML:

```
<link 
 href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script 
   src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Some Title</h2>
     </div>

 <div class="block">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
          <img class="img-left" src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg"/>
        <div class="content-heading"><h3>Experience &nbsp </h3></div>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
     <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem 
    malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
<br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
     <img class="img-right" src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp- 
  content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg"/>
     <div class="content-heading"><h3>Experience &nbsp </h3></div>
     <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .span4 img {
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
 .span4 .img-left {
 float: left;
 }
 .span4 .img-right {
 float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` and set `padding-right` if the `img` is before text

```css
.text-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
.p-right{
 padding-right: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div>
    <h1 >text1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" />
  </div>
 
</div> 
<div class="text-container p-right">

  <div>
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" />
  </div>
   <div>
    <h1 >text1</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="text-container">
  <div>
    <h1 >text1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" />
  </div>
 
</div> 
<div class="text-container p-right">

  <div>
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" />
  </div>
   <div>
    <h1 >text1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?